# Internal vs Exported References to Module Methods

Tags: javascript, reference, es6-modules

I'm trying to better understand the how & why of differences between references to an internal module method vs the reference that is created when that same method is exported.

I'm not even sure my terminology is correct, and searching for information has not turned up anything useful.

A simplified example ...I have a simple module that performs some maths:

```
export const doubleNumber = (num) => {
  return num * 2
}

export const squareNumber = (num) => {
  return num * num
}

export default {
  double: (num) => doubleNumber(num),
  square: (num) => squareNumber(num),
}
```

...and I have some unit tests to verify functionality:

```
import * as numProvider from './number-provider'

describe('the default methods', () => {
  it('should call the correct math method when its property method is called', () => {
    const doubleSpy = jest.spyOn(numProvider, 'doubleNumber')

    const result = numProvider.default.double(1)

    expect(result).toBe(2)
    expect(doubleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
  })
})
```

([example project with the above code](https://github.com/BenjaminWFox/javascript-module-tests-reference))

Now when I run my test it fails. From what I understand, the method I'm spying on (the exported method), is never called because `numProvider.default.double` is referencing the internal method.

I can verify this (and fix the test) by attaching the exported method to the default export object instead, `double: (num) => exports.doubleNumber(num)` but then of course the site breaks because `exports` is not defined in the browser.

**So my question (I think?) is..**

What is JavaScript (or some other process?) doing that causes the creation of these two separate references?

Comment: I would guess you don't even need modules to do that. Just create an object that contains the methods and spy on it. The function you call still refers to the local `const` variable, not to the object method.

Comment: Exports are properties on an object.  In your case, those properties contain references to functions.  When you `spyOn()` those properties, it is only able to spy on function calls made through those properties.  It's not able to spy on calls directly to the underlying function.  So, in this case, it's spying on `numProvider.doubleNumber` and not spying on the actual const definition of `doubleNumber` in the other module.  It will only record how many times `numProvider.doubleNumber()` is called, not how many times `doubleNumber()` is called.

Comment: FYI, this is not specific to exports.  This just has to do with spying on a copied reference to a function that is in a property of an object.  You're only spying on calls made through that object property, not spying on underlying calls to the function itself.  Javascript doesn't allow you to replace the underlying function itself so jest doesn't have an ability to hook it.  It can only replace stored references to that function and thus can only monitor calls made through those stored references, not to the underlying function itself.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks, I feel like you're pointing my brain in the right direction. I'm still missing something related to the fundamentals, but I'll do some more digging based on your comments and see what I can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is JavaScript (or some other process?) doing that causes the creation of these two separate references?

The crux of the issue is that exports are properties on an object that contain separate references to functions within the module and you're only spying on function calls made through the exported property on the object.  You're not spying on the underlying function itself so calls made directly to the underlying function are not monitored.

In fact, the Javascript language doesn't provide a way to spy on the underlying core function when all you have is a reference to it.  Calls to the core function are made through whatever reference you have.  Declaring a function creates a symbol and assigns it a reference to the function you declared.  Declaring an export for that creates a property on an object and assigns it another reference to the same underlying function.

Spying on the object hooks the function reference in that object (replaces it with a monitoring function) and it can only monitor calls that are made through that object property because only those will actually call the replacement monitoring function.

I'll give you an example using plain objects so you can see what's going on without the added distraction of exports:

```js
// simple version of spyOn
const spy = function(obj, methodName) {
    let orig = obj[methodName];
    obj[methodName] = function() {
         console.log(`spyhit for obj.${methodName}()`);
    }
}

// core function
const doubleNumber = function(num) {
     return num * 2
}

// object that contains reference to core function
const myObj = {
     double: doubleNumber
};

// lets spy on myObj.double
spy(myObj, "double");

myObj.double(1);    // generates spyhit
doubleNumber(1);    // does not generate spyhit
```

Here you can see that only calls made through the actual property that you spied on `myObj.double()` are actually spied on.  There's no spying of the actual core function.

This is because `myObj.double` is all that the spy function is given.  That property contains a reference to `doubleNumber`, but isn't the actual function itself. The `spy()` method here (similar to what jest is doing) just replaces the actual property with a monitoring function so that it can record when it's called.  But, it has no ability to replace the actual core function itself.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! For some reason I was thinking there was a difference in how the references functioned in the named vs default exports. This helped clear that misconception and clarified how the spy method works. I read an additional article that helped reinforce what you're saying about references, https://medium.com/@naveenkarippai/learning-how-references-work-in-javascript-a066a4e15600

Comment: Another similarly helpful article: https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0